# Myslq2 nodejs database query returning old data

Tags: mysql, node.js

every time I run this code, my `id` variable always has a value that is not in the database anymore, I have tried restarting the database and my computer to no avail, what am I doing wrong?

````js
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

let bot; 
let token;
let id = '';
let botName;

// create the connection to database
const c = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'monkeybot'
});


//grab initial data from database
c.execute("SELECT * FROM `info`", (err, results, fields) =>{
    token = results[0].token;
    id = results[0].self_id;

    c.query("SELECT * FROM `people`", (err, results, fields) =>{
        console.log(results)
        botName = results[0];

        console.log("token: " + token);
        console.log("id: " + id);
        console.log("name: " + botName);
        console.log("-----------------------");
    });
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the console.log you are getting, because my initial assumption is that the 'id' and token are comng as undefined, if thats the case chain the prommises whit a .then or use the much simpler async await. In any case you are trying to query two different tables and i asume use the data from both queries, it would be better if you can write it as a JOIN between the tables if they have a primary and foregin key relation. A nother way to go would be to make two functions that each queries a table and return the result, that way you can use them down the line.

Comment: so i can't exactly show you the output of the console because there's my private token in there but i can tell you that it is in fact equal to the old and incorrect data i put into the database before i changed it, i would love to use .then or async/await but i can't seem to use it correctly no matter how much i try, a join could potentially help but if the data it gets from the first table is wrong, the data from the second one will be ```undefined```